# Firebase Authentication Impact on Google Ads Campaign Data Retention in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

I'm encountering a challenge in my Flutter app related to Firebase Authentication and Google Ads campaign data. I'd appreciate some guidance on this matter.

Context:

I've implemented custom event tracking in my Flutter app to monitor user behavior, including data associated with Google Ads campaigns.

Users access my app through Google Ads campaigns, and I'm successfully capturing campaign-specific data.

The Issue:

The problem arises when a user signs in using Firebase Authentication. Prior to sign-in, I can view and access campaign data without any issues. However, after a user signs in, it seems that the campaign data gets lost or deleted.

Specifically:

Data associated with the campaign is visible when the user is not signed in.
However, after the user signs in using Firebase Authentication, the campaign data is no longer accessible.
Questions:

Why is this happening?: I'm curious about the underlying cause of this issue. Why would Firebase Authentication impact the retention of campaign data?

How can I prevent this from happening?: What steps can I take to ensure that the campaign data remains intact even after a user signs in via Firebase Authentication?

I'm eager to hear from the Stack Overflow community regarding any insights or advice on addressing this issue and maintaining consistent tracking of campaign data, particularly in scenarios where users sign in. Your expertise and assistance are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What I've Tried:

I've reviewed my Firebase Authentication setup to ensure it's correctly integrated with my app.

I've double-checked my custom event tracking code to confirm that it's functioning correctly.

There is data available before the users is signed in but as soon as the sign in process happen thats also tracked with the campaign but the events after this is 0

Expectation:

I expected that campaign data would continue to be accessible and associated with users, even after they sign in with Firebase Authentication. My goal is to maintain consistent tracking of campaign data throughout the user's journey in the app, regardless of their sign-in status.

I'm eager to hear from the Stack Overflow community regarding any insights or advice on addressing this issue. Your expertise and assistance are greatly appreciated. Thank you!